# The code is working properly on gcc compiler but when I submitted it to a coding portal (SPOJ) then it shows run time error, Why?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, realloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int *p=(int*)malloc(10*4);
   int i,a,count=1;
   printf("Input :\n");
   for(i=0;i<10*count;i++)
   {
     scanf("%d",p+i);
     if(*(p+i)==22){
         break;
        }
     if(i==9+(count-1)*10){
          realloc(p,(10+10*count)*sizeof(int));
          count++;
       }
    }
    printf("\nOutput :\n");
    i=0;
    for(;;){
        if(*(p+i)==22){
           break;
        }
        printf("%d\n",*(p+i));
        i++;
     }
}
```

The mooto the the code is to take the inputs continously untill 22 is encountered and when 22 is encountered then it prints all the values which I have entered precedding it
SPOJ runs the code on Ideone.com

Comment: You might want to tell us *what* error you get.

Comment: *** Error in `./prog': realloc(): invalid old size: 0x09654008 *** @BoPersson

Comment: What happens if the user inputs more than a 3 digit number?  Also, you will be overwriting your buffer.  Assuming 2 digits of input each time, first read loads p[0] and p[1], second loads p[1] and p[2], etc.  Although fixing as amyCU indicates, your code doesn't make much sense.  Also please format so it's readable.

Comment: You really need to sort out indention and code formatting. As your question stands now, it is unclear what you are asking because the code is unreadable.

Comment: Leave my answer , but i dont understand why you need `realloc` in first place.

Comment: BTW if you are printing the cues "Input" and "Output" for a SPOJ submission, you'll probably get "Wrong Answer". There is always an example: go strictly by that.

Comment: You are not assigning the result of `realloc` back to `p` (after checking it isn't NULL of course).

Answer (score 0):

God I'm slow.

```
*** Error in `./prog': realloc(): invalid old size: 0x09654008 ***
```

Here's what the most likely problem is:

1. After the first `malloc` call, `p` is set to some heap address (let's call it `0x1000`);
2. The first `realloc` can't resize the buffer in its current location, so it allocates a *new* buffer at a different address (call it `0x2000`) and marks the buffer starting at `0x1000` as available for use;
3. You don't update `p` to point to this new buffer;
4. *Something* overwrites the memory starting at `0x1000`, clobbering whatever metadata was stored about the buffer size;
5. You call `realloc` again, but since `p` is still `0x1000`, `realloc` tries to resize a previously-freed buffer which has since been overwritten;
6. Whatever metadata your `malloc` implementation was using has since been overwritten for that old buffer, hence the error.

You need to save the value returned from `realloc`, as it may be potentially different from `p` (including `NULL` if the request could not be satisfied):

```
int *tmp = realloc( p, sizeof *p * ( 10 + 10 * count ) );
if ( tmp )
  p = tmp;
else
  // realloc failed, handle as appropriate
```

You'll have to make sure `p` and `tmp` are the same type.

Also, change your initial `malloc` call to

```
int *p = malloc( sizeof *p * 10 );
```

Casting the result of `malloc` and `realloc` is discouraged in C<sup>1</sup>, and `sizeof *p` gives the same result as `sizeof (int)`, with the added benefit of if you ever change the type of `p` (from `int *` to `long *`) you won't have to change the parameters to `malloc` or `realloc` - `sizeof *p` will always give you the right answer.

---

<sup>1.  Yes, in C++ you must cast the result of `malloc`, but if you were writing C++ you wouldn't be using `malloc` in the first place (for this exercise, you'd just use a `std::vector<int>` which can grow as necessary).</sup>